# Make array from jquery serialized string

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, deserialization

I have serialized string for jquery:

```
[{"id":1},
 {"id":2,"children":[{"id":3}]},
 {"id":4,"children":[{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6,"children":[{"id":7}]}]}]},
 {"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10}
]
```

I want to pharse this in PHP to get something like:

```
        $menu = array(
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 1',  'id' => '1' ,'children' => '0'), 
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 2',  'id' => '2' ,'children' => '0'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 3',  'id' => '3' ,'children' => '2'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 4',  'id' => '4' ,'children' => '0'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 5',  'id' => '5' ,'children' => '4'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 6',  'id' => '6' ,'children' => '5'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 7',  'id' => '7' ,'children' => '6'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 8',  'id' => '8' ,'children' => '0'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 9',  'id' => '9' ,'children' => '0'),  
                  array( 'name' => 'Item 10', 'id' => '10','children' => '0'),  
               );
```

(When children == 0, then this item is root category.)

Many thanks for sugestions.
Karlis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out PHP's `json_decode` function, [documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: Thanks Joseph for answer. About json_decode i know, but in my jquery string is childrens and there need ( i think some recursive functioin? )